# Function to balance a search tree

Tags: c, tree, binary-search-tree

So I need some help on this since I'm reading from a file and inserting into a list and a tree for search purposes, this function is not saving all the nodes, it loses the information while running.

```
fe=left child
fd=right child
```

NodeCount returns how many nodes are in the Tree and the rotate functions are working properly

```
TREE *rotate left(TREE *A) //right just replace fe for fd:
{
     ARVORE *aux;
     aux=A->fd;
     A->fd=aux->fe;
     aux->fe=A;
     return A;
}
```

the balance function returns 1 if the tree is balanced and 0 if not

```
TREE *balances (TREE *A)
{
      TREE *aux = A;
      if(aux == NULL)
         return A;

      while(!balance(aux))
      {
           if((NodeCount(aux->fe) - NodeCount(aux->fd)) > 1)
                aux=rotateright(aux);
            if((NodeCount(aux->fd) - NodeCount(aux->fe)) > 1)
                 aux=rotateleft(aux);
            return aux;
      }
      return A;
}


    output :
    before balances :0
    01gwztbs0d@yahoo.com
    2v7t5k72fb@clix.pt
    2v7t5k72fb@clix.pt
    3ahf@sapo.pt
    bysws@clix.pt
    cop8m5@clix.pt lost
    ibnor@yahoo.com lost
    lglkge@clix.pt lost
    sck0z@yahoo.com lost
    After Balances
    01gwztbs0d@yahoo.com
    2v7t5k72fb@clix.pt
    2v7t5k72fb@clix.pt
    3ahf@sapo.pt
    bysws@clix.pt
    Equi:1
```

Comment: "this function is not saving all the nodes". Which function are you referring to? Please provide a [Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including the test input, the expected behaviour and the actual behaviour.

Comment: the balances funcion,the function doesn't return the right root of the tree

Comment: I'm reading about 1000 emails from a file and in the tree only has a few, but the emails are all read which I know because i'm inserting them into a linked list aswell and they are on the list @kaylum

Comment: @kaylum I think this will help you understand what's happening

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is logical. Your if-statements are not logically connected with each other and the conditions overlap. As a result `aux` is overwritten with all the statements of the second `if` and then returned as such.

**Example**: first `aux = cop8m5@clix.pt;` then `aux = 01gwztbs0d@yahoo.com;` and `01gwztbs0d@yahoo.com` is returned.

If you look closely, you would see that what is missing, is exactly the right partial subtree (all elements greater than the root). As it looks it is an `inorder` traversal, so therefore the root must be `bysws@clix.pt`. From here you can easily see it yourself.

The quickest solution is to put one `return aux;` in the body of each if-statement:

```
while(!balance(aux)) {
       if ((NodeCount(aux->fe) - NodeCount(aux->fd)) > 1) {
           aux=rotateright(aux);
           return aux;
       }
       if ((NodeCount(aux->fd) - NodeCount(aux->fe)) > 1) {
           aux=rotateleft(aux);
           return aux;
       }
}
```

Comment: @euphz2011 Welcome to SO! Since you are (relatively) new, you might want to check this [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)